# Spring URI Template Patterns with Regular Expressions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hey someone know how can match this URI "http://localhost:8080/test/user/127.0.0.1:8002:8" with @RequestMapping.

I try to write this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
        headers = "Accept=application/xml")
public void test(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    System.out.println(id);
    return null;
}
```

but the problem is when i print the id the value is: `127.0.0`.
Maybe something is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried url encoding and then decoding the `id` variable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the SpEL documentation:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html

You will want to do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/xml" )
public void test(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `@Configuration`-style with Spring MVC, this will do the trick:

```
@Configuration
public class Api extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        return mapping;
    }

}
```

As you can see you must disable [`useSuffixPatternMatch`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#setUseSuffixPatternMatch%28boolean%29) in `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

### See also:

- [Configuring RequestMappingHandlerMapping when using mvc:annotation-driven](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?120192)

Comment: This would have a global effect, wouldn't it be better to use SpEL in his particular instance?

Comment: @aweigold: it depends on what OP wants. But +1 to your answer/solution, looks promising.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to remove the @EnableWebMvc when you actually extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport http://rstoyanchev.github.com/spring-mvc-31-indepth/#25

Comment: Thanks, this snippet helped me in a different situation.