# How to use a regex path mapper variable in a RequestMapping?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use a request mapper to match on urls like this:

```
http://localhost:9999/si/configs/some/path/on/the/server/file.xml
```

I have a controller set up like this, but the value of the `RequestMapping` of the `findConfig` method is incorrect.  Here is my code (stripped clean of everything extraneous):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/si/configs")
public class SIController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{path:/**/*.xml}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> findConfig(@PathVariable("path") String path) {
        // value of path arg should be: "/some/path/on/the/server/file.xml"
   }
}
```

I know that Spring allows for regex's in path matching strings, and I tried to follow the advice of this question: [Spring URI Template Patterns with Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020444/spring-uri-template-patterns-with-regular-expressions), but I can't seem to get this correct.

What should go in the request mapping?

---

**EDIT**

When I remove the path variable and go with this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/**/*.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> findConfig() {
    }
```

My controller method is invoked as expected.  So, there is something about trying to match on a path variable with wild crads that spring doesn't like.

Comment: If you are sure your path mapping is correct, make sure the .xml suffix is not stripped off by Spring content negotiation.

Comment: When I debugged, the xml suffix is still around.  I'm just not sure of the correct syntax for inside the path variable.

Comment: Edited the question to add more info.

Comment: I'm not sure if PathVariable could resolve mutiple "/" like "foo/bar".

Comment: @Hippoom I don't care if I use a PathVariable or not. I just want to capture the last part of the path in the request mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using HttpServletRequest direclty?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/*.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> findConfig(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String path = request.getServletPath()/getRequestURL()/getPathInfo()
    //I forget which one could give the correct part, maybe some parse operation needed
```

}